# Check if browser process is running

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, process

How can I check if browser is running ?

I start process by:

```
Process.Start("http://google.com");
```

But I want only have one browser/tab. I think I should use `Process.GetProcessesByName`.

Comment: What about if it's open without the website you want?